# Simplecart 2.0 Email not complete

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I've installed simplecart 2 jquery cart, and have modified it to email the basket to me, including adding some aditional forms for the user to fill out first. After a lot of work, I've managed to get the cart to send the email, but only the user fields are filled, and the contents of the basket don't seem to be getting passed to the sendjs.php page.

Within my index page, I have the following script in the head section to ensure simplecart uses email as the checkout method.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

simpleCart.email = "MY EMAIL ADDRESS";
simpleCart.checkoutTo = Email;
simpleCart.currency = GBP;

simpleCart.cartHeaders = ["Thumb_image_noHeader", "Name" , "Size_input_div_div", "Price" , "decrement_noHeader" , "Quantity", "increment_noHeader", "remove_noHeader", "Total" ];

</script>
```

Further down I have the code that generates the checkout button which calls a function enquire:

```
<form action="sendjs.php" name="form" method="post">
<input placeholder="Name" type="text" name="name"  value="name" id="name" />
<input placeholder="Contact Number" type="text" name="phone" value="phone" id="phone" />
<input placeholder="Email" type="text" name="email" value="email" id="email" /> 
<input placeholder="Message" type="text" name="message" value="message" id="message" />     
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:enquire();" class="simpleCart_checkout">Checkout</a>
</form>
```

Within Simplecart.js, I have the following function which should pass the required info to sendjs.php:

```
    me.emailCheckout = function enquire() {    

itemsString = "";
for( var current in me.items ){ 
    var item = me.items[current];
    itemsString += item.name + " " + item.quantity + " " + item.price + "\n";
} 

name = document.form.name.value;
phone = document.form.phone.value;
email = document.form.email.value;

me.total += "" + " GBP"

var form = document.createElement("form");
form.style.display = "none";
form.method = "POST";
form.action = "sendjs.php";
form.acceptCharset = "ISO-8859-1";
form.appendChild(me.createHiddenElement("jcitems", itemsString));
form.appendChild(me.createHiddenElement("jctotal", me.total));  
form.appendChild(me.createHiddenElement("name", name));
form.appendChild(me.createHiddenElement("phone", phone));
form.appendChild(me.createHiddenElement("email", email));
document.body.appendChild(form);
form.submit();
document.form.submit();
document.body.removeChild(form);    
}
```

Finally, I have sendjs.php which is what generates the email:

```
<?php
/*include 'simpleCart.js';*/

$to      = 'MY EMAIL ADDRESS';
$subject = 'Order Inquiry';
$jcitems = " <p><b>ORDER:</b></p> <p> " . $_POST['jcitems']."</p>" .     "<p><b>Total:</b>     $" . $_POST['jctotal']."</p>";
$time = date ("h:i A"); 
$date = date ("l, F jS, Y");
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: EMAIL' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: EMAIL' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$text = "<html><body><p>This form was submitted on Your Web Site on \n $date at\n $time</p><p><b>Message:</b>\n$message</p><p><b>Customers Email Address:</b>$email</p><p><b>Customers Name:</b> $name </p><p><b>Customers Phone Number:</b> $phone </p></html></body>";
$body = $text . $jcitems;
mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
/*Clearing the cart info after succesfull order is made*/
setcookie ("simpleCart", "", time() - 3600);

Header('Location: success.html');

echo "success!";

?>
```

So when the user clicks Checkout, they get taken to success.html which works, it sends me an email, but the contents of the cart are missing.

Any idea why the email isn't including the contents of the cart?

Any help would be great guys, this is becoming a pain..

(I've taken out my email to stop spam bots..)